# Errors getting Selenium running on rails 4 with Safari, chrome or Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

I am trying to get selenium (thru Capybara) working on a rails 4, ruby 2.0.0 environment using rspec.  I have tried using every browser by setting config settings in my spec_helper.rb.  Example with Safari;

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :safari)
end
```

For all browsers, I have made sure that the appropriate driver (e.g. safaridriver) is in `$PATH`.
test example (obviously no Javascript/AJAX here, just trying to get it to work);

```
it 'should post to the publication endpoint', :vcr do
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
  visit root_path
  Capybara.use_default_driver
end
```

on `visit root_path`, i get the following error;

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError:
       timed out waiting for Safari to respond
```

Environment

```
rails (4.0.0.beta1)
ruby 2.0.0p0
webmock (1.9.3)
capybara (2.0.2)
selenium-webdriver (2.31.0)
```

I have been trying to get this to work for two days now so any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The SafariDriver is implemented as a Safari browser extension. That means you need to install it before using Safari with Selenium. Please follow the steps from: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriverInternals

> Sign up for Apple's (free) Safari Developer Program and generate a signed certificate for the extension.
>
> > Build the SafariDriver extension:
> > ./go safari
>
> Install the extension:
>
> > Launch Safari
> > Enable the Develop menu (Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar)
> > Open the Extension Builder (Develop > Show Extension Builder)
> > Add a new extension: $SELENIUM_CLIENT/build/javascript/safari-driver/SafariDriver.safariextension
> > Click Install